# Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: api-key, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to create a script in Python which converts audio files into text. I found the module Google Cloud Speech which can easily do it for me. I found out that you need to create credentials (API key) for using their services. I tried to create credentials and it said that I have to create a billing account which requires credit card.

So, how does it work?

Is that free?

Do I have to pay to get my script work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google-cloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/speech) is a client for [Google Cloud Speech-to-Text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/), i.e. a library which enables you to programmatically use google's models to perform speech transcription using python ("module" is not the best term in this context). You **do** need to use credentials in order to authenticate yourself or your app, however, using an API key is not the only way to do so (check [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) for more). Now, in order to do any of that, you would have to create a google cloud project which in turns means you will have to obtain a billing account. This does not necessarily mean that you will get charged: there's a [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/) which gives you $300 for 12 months ([here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions) is the FAQ for more details). You should go through the above links and then go ahead with the client libraries' [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you did not add any credit card in your account as it need to add credit card.
Go to [Billing Section](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) and add a credit card. Then you will get $300 for a year.
With that you can make your script working for free.

Comment: Well,it will be free for a year or until you spend all of your 300$ right?

Comment: One more question,Does it cost money(from my 300$) to send requests to google cloud speech(thorugh the script) or it`s free during the free trail?

Comment: it will deduct from the $300